# Broken SSD. What should I do?

Tags: ssd

It seems my SSD is broken. I can't boot my laptop. The SSD including operating system does not appear in the boot menu anymore anymore.
Is there an easy way to repair the SSD or to extract all my data from it?

Can anyone tell me the experience of a similar case?

[image]

Comment: The first thing to check, since you've removed it, is if it's properly seated when inside your PC. Put it back into place and make sure it's in contact with the slot you put it in (assuming there's only one; if there's more, try a different one). Do that with the power source off. If it's a laptop and you can remove the battery, do so, and unplug it from the power brick. If it's a desktop, well, do the same, minus the battery. It's hard to tell from this one picture if your SSD is fried, or if it's something else that's causing your problem.

Comment: Yes, I have already performed and tested this step.
From the outside I see no damage.

Comment: With your SSD in place, go into the BIOS, and disable the CSM module in the Boot or Security tab. Save changes and restart. EDIT: while you're at it, make sure your SATA mode is on AHCI.

Comment: The same result. The computer still does not recognize the SSD.

Comment: Do you have a Windows or Linux live install USB drive handy, or can you get one from a friend? (I know it's difficult with the lockdown, but I assume you've got another computer since you're posting your question here) If you can put a bootable ISO of Windows, or Linux, on a USB drive and boot from it (make the appropriate changes in your BIOS), then you'll see if your SSD does show up or not, but it not showing up in BIOS is not good news... It's probably badly seated, that's usually what happens with M2 drives.

Comment: I have already started the computer from the UBS stick. But unfortunately the SSD did not appear there.

Comment: Then you've got to try it into a different PC, to check if it's toast, or if your mobo is defective.

Comment: I don't have another computer to check the ssd with :(

Comment: Then you're going to have to wait until the lockdown is lifted, and bring it to a repair shop to have it tested. They'll have an M.2 adapter to fit it in, and examine, if not the content, at least its operability. If it's toast, you'll have to replace it. Those SSD are getting cheaper and cheaper, and with all those weeks of not doing business, I'm sure you'll get a fair price for a new one, maybe even upgrade in sizes.